# put aggregation distinct count in else if tableau

Tags: tableau-api

so i want to put calculate field, if the contains selected product, then it appear number of count order (id for  transaction) of that product (on this case, using count distinct for order_match_id (its the id for every transaction)

im using this

```
 IF CONTAINS([Selected Product], [Name])
THEN (CNTD([Order Match Id])
ELSE NULL
END
```

but its says `Expected Closing paranthesis for the expression starting at characted 47`

the point is, i want to make some else if condition, if the condition true, then appearing count distinct of id transaction to provide how many transaction

Comment: you have an extra "(" in the second line, between then and cntd

Comment: do you mean? IF CONTAINS([Selected Product], [Name])
THEN ((CNTD([Order Match Id]))
ELSE NULL
END ?

Comment: if that, then its still same erorr sir

Comment: or do you mean THEN CNTD([Order Match Id]) ? if so, then its unknown function CNTD called

Comment: you have multiple problems: 1) cntd is not a Tableau functions since you should use COUNTD; 2) you're aggregating inside an if statement based on non-aggregated value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you may want to add more logic to your statement, you should remember that you cannot mix aggregated with non aggregated values.

Basically, your formula should be more like this:

```
COUNTD(IF CONTAINS([Selected Product], [Name])
THEN [Order ID]
ELSE NULL
END)
```

Doing so, "first" you test your condition for each row and "then" you aggregate values using COUNTD (not cntd)

Comment: Correct answer, but the “ELSE NULL” is unnecessary FYI

Comment: idk this is the good answer or not, but i've tried my answer and already applied on my tableau dashboard, what do you think about my answer?

Comment: if your answers is same like mine, then i will mark this as an answer

Comment: if your answers is same like mine, then i will mark this as an answer

Comment: I would say that yours still depends on your additional needs; that's why I would prefer (mine) using countd as a wrapper for the internal statemant without using attr twice if not needed

Answer (score 0):

after posting this question on tableau community, this is the best answer so far

they are probably not the right dimensions but see the use of atta and countd

```
IF CONTAINS(attr([Kategori]), attr([Name]))

 THEN COUNTD([Order Match Id])

 ELSE NULL

 END
```